# How to make buttons with download and open options

Tags: php, html, button, download

I created some buttons but when you click on them, it simply opens the file. I would like to have a 'save as' function when I write click them with the mouse.  Currently when I write click and select 'save as', it downloads an html file instead of the actual file.

Here is my code:

```
$handle = opendir('mydirectory');

if($handle){
     while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false){
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && $entry != '.htaccess'){

       echo "<button onclick=\"location.href='mydirectory/$entry'\"    style=\"background-color: #660000;\"><p style=color:white;>$entry</button><br>";

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
```

Comment: Sounds like a webserver problem. Not a php one, since you don't use php to serve the file.

Comment: Is there any way to at least get an 'edit' option on right click?